# Passenger: Don't know how to build task 'nginx'

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I am using Passenger gem in my rails app. I don't know how but its path is changed to ruby2.0.0 from ruby1.9.3. When i restart my nginx server, i get error:

```
 Restarting nginx: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'passenger_root' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'passenger_root' directive, whichever is applicable. (-1: Unknown error)
```

When i run this command:

```
rake nginx
```

It gives:

```
Don't know how to build task 'nginx'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am not getting how to make this work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In which directory did you run 'rake nginx', and why did you run 'rake nginx'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked!

In my /opt/nginx, path for passenger was given for ruby 2.0.0, i changed it to ruby 1.9.3 and worked!